# Lucifer fanfic-story: Feather used to conceive Chloe/Trixie, finger to conceive Jesus

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, lucifer-2016

I'm looking for a fanfiction story based on the *Lucifer* TV-show.  I probably read it on ArchiveOfOurOwn, but it may also been elsewhere.

In the story, angels who wanted to help a human to conceive a special child had to sacrifice something divine — for Jesus, the angel sacrificed (part of) his little finger... which he was still missing.

It turns out that Lucifer lost a feather (or two) in the gates when he was kicked out of Heaven — and this was used to conceive Chloe, or possibly Trixie.  Either way, Chloe's previous contact with Lucifer's divinity is what makes her immune to him.

Lucifer does not take the news of his "fatherhood" well.

I think Lucifer is given the second feather.

I think it was Aminadel who used the feather.

So does this sound familiar?  Does anyone remember the title and author?  (And maybe have it saved?)

PS: I actually think it was Trixie, and she's some kind of prophet... or maybe I'm mixing with another story.

Comment: Can you give us a rough time-frame of when you read this? Was it in the past year? Roughly how long was it ( a short story/novel length/UBER long). Was it in English? Are there any other phrases/scenes that stand out to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

It was ["Chosen One"](https://archiveofourown.org/works/7627813) by [PokerFace84](https://archiveofourown.org/users/PokerFace84/pseuds/PokerFace84):

https://archiveofourown.org/works/7627813

Summary:
Takes place after season 1 final. Lucifer's mother is out of Hell, hiding and plotting... something. Meanwhile a new very odd case turns up, a handsome new detective is hired by the police department and Trixie gets into real troubles going beyond this world. And then there are these stupid feelings... Can one Devil solve all this and live to tell the tale?